# How to prevent changing parent's width on resize

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I got a question: I have an image in a div. the image is bigger that the div and it has `height:100%` to make it look ok. So when I do a resize image becomes bigger and it looks fine. but when I resize the browser to make it smaller image becomes smaller, but its parent saves the width of the original image. In fact it just takes the width of an image. I got a fiddle for you, just try to resize your browser or the output section to see the red background appear. I'm curious is there any chance to make the div dimenstions the same as the image's dynamically. I need the container dimensions cause I have some other elements besides the image and they use the coordinates of the div. thanks.

important! it works the way I saw it only in FireFox. Chrome's behaviour is different.

```css
.img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;

    background-color: red;
}

.gallery-image {
  bottom: 90px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 25px;
    background-color: grey;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-image">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img src="http://www.ibm.com/big-data/us/en/images/bigdata_homepage_maininfographic_345x194.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide all relevant code IN the question and not through a link.  Thanks!

Comment: Have in mind that the div can expand freely on the X axis; your image can't because it has to maintain the proportion to the height.

Comment: it is because the height is set by absolute positioning top and bottom as the browser is resized the bottom changes and scroller is visible thats the reason the height changes try adding a fixed height you will see the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done with CSS using background-image:url("http://www.ibm.com/big-data/us/en/images/bigdata_homepage_maininfographic_345x194.jpg").. This way your image and div become one object.  Then you just control the div and the background image size accordingly.
Side Note... It helps with performance as well.

Comment: I just tried your version, but I don't get it. can background image scale with the div saving the aspect ratio?

Comment: yes it can, you just have just set the size; repeat; or origin settings depending on what you want to do with it.    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size    is good reference

Comment: http://www.psychicpower.com/ ... look at the main hero image and change the size of the browser's width.  I needed the height to stay the same but had to change the width depending on screen size.     I used background-image:        url("../img/img_hero_home.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-position: right;

Comment: I mean I got the same result. The `.img-wrapper` div is still 100% width. it acts like before. I used `background-size: contain, background-position: center`. but how to tell the wrapper be the same width as the background image..

Comment: sorry but no... I need as my fiddle above, but without red background. I need the wrapper div being the same with as image. like image changes the size of wrapper when you do resize...

Comment: The way everything works is parent down to children.  You cannot go the other way unless you use Javascript to overwrite this.  You have all the red because you have set the div to be that tall.  You cannot make a picture that has a 3x6 aspect ratio and make it 6x3... you just cant unless you crop some of it off.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the minimum dimensions of an image so it won't become any smaller like this

```
 img {
     min-height: 200px;
     min-width: 400px;
 }
```

Comment: Right, I had the CSS rules in img-wrapper. I changed it to img. You should better give a class to the images and add the rule only for this class. Check it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ro5kur3/), I can't get it to work on stackoverflow.